# Another fun riddle

Tags: riddle

I am second of my compatriots,
and, out loud, I am, by definition. 
I can be true or false, positive and negative,
and, in a body, accompanied by my predecessor. 
Raise me in a computer and I am eight times longer,
but know that some are allergic to me.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are:

> B

I am second of my compatriots

> The second letter of the alphabet

Out loud, I am, by definition.

> When spoken, to "be"

True or false

> To be, or not to be.

Positive and negative

> Blood type of b-positive or b-negative

In a body, accompanied by my predecessor.

> "Ab" as in abdominal muscles

Raise me in a computer and I am eight times longer,

> I'm still working on this one, something to do with there being 8 bits in a byte.

But know that some are allergic to me.

> Some people have bee allergies

Comment: You're not completely correct, but you have it in general.
In a body, accompanied by my predecessor -> the Blood type AB
Raise me in a computer and I am eight times longer -> a bit (b) is the eighth of a byte (B)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of hiccups in the reasoning, but I'm relatively certain that you are a

> BYTE.

Second after...

> bit

Out loud...

> Like a sound byte.

True/False can be expressed...

> in a single byte.

In a body...

> could this be in a human body (bite) AKA baby teeth or gums?

In a computer...

> One byte is expressed as 8 bits.

Allergies...

> People can be allergic to bug (or other types of) bites.

Comment: I was typing the same, but oh well, you were faster. My thought about body/predecessor was maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble).

Comment: Nope. Close, but no cigar.

Comment: @Seraviel, can you elaborate any further?  It seems most people looking at this would come to a similar conclusion.  Is it way off base?  Are some deductions correct?

Comment: The answer is one-fourth correct. More would be a big hint.